# Evaluating a limit of an integral

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I have a function $f(x,y,z) :\mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, a smooth function.
I know that 
$$
I = \int_{z \in \mathbb{R}}\int_{y \in \mathbb{R}}\int_{x \in \mathbb{R}} f(x,y,z) \ dx dydz
$$
this integral converges. However, it does not converge absolutely, i.e.
$$
\int_{z \in \mathbb{R}}\int_{y \in \mathbb{R}}\int_{x \in \mathbb{R}} |f(x,y,z)| \ dx dydz = \infty.
$$

My question is the following: Does the following limit always hold?
$$
I = \lim_{\varepsilon \rightarrow 0} \int_{-L_1}^{L_1} 
\int_{-L_2}^{L_2} \int_{-L_3}^{L_3} e^{- \varepsilon x^2}f(x,y,z) \ dx dydz,
$$
where $L_1, L_2, L_3$ grows to infinity as $\varepsilon$ goes to $0$.

If it was absolutely convergent then it is clear from the dominated convergence theorem. But I wasn't sure about this case...
I would appreciate any comments, hints and suggestions. Thank you very much.

Comment: What's your definition of $\int_{z \in \mathbb{R}}\int_{y \in \mathbb{R}}\int_{x \in \mathbb{R}} f(x,y,z) \ dx dydz$?

Comment: I added that $f$ is smooth, so I was thinking Lebesgue measure or Riemann integral (which I think is equivalent as long as I assume it's smooth?)